# How to put a scroll in accrodion

Tags: html, css

I have text box and names in the accordion. Accordion is perfectly working but while implementing scroll due to exceeds the text box and names its not working. I have attached the image here to design it like image but scroll,but text box and label are misplacing.

I tried to design as like this image:

[image]

```html
        <!----Starts second column-------->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #b3daff;">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                        style="color: red"></span></a> <a data-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><span
                                        style="font-weight: 700;">Educational Details</span><span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: red">&nbsp;</span></a>

                                </h4>

                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12" id="ex1">
                                        <div class="row" id="text">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-md-12">Degree
                                                                Stream 
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <br />

                                                <!-- Address line 1 -->
                                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">10th</label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <br /> <br />

                                                <!-- Address line 1 -->
                                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">12th</label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>


                                                <br /> <br />

                                                <!-- Address line 1 -->
                                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Degree</label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                                <br /> <br />

                                                <!-- Address line 1 -->
                                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Masters</label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>


                                                <br /> <br />

                                                <!-- Address line 1 -->
                                                <div class="col-md-12">

                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Certificate</label>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp"
                                                                    required placeholder="Address Line 1" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!----Ends second column-------->
                    </div>
                    <!----Ends accordion column-------->
```

Comment: That's a lot of HTML for people to look at. Have you tried putting overflow-y css styling on the div that needs the overflow? :)

Comment: No css so your table flows vertically. Please provide full example. And then do what Imdad said and apply overflow-y: auto;

Comment: Yes. I tried scroll is not working. In image there are 6 text boxes but i am unable to place it in accordion.

Comment: #ex1 { width: 510px;overflow-x: scroll;} .. I added this in my css but not working. Due to i took row, col-md-12.

Answer (score 0):

To make it scrollable, add `overflow-x:scroll` to the `panel-body` class.

```
#collapseTwo .panel-body {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

To give it something to scroll, give the `#ex1` div inside that panel a width of something greater than 100% to push the size into an overflow area.

```
#ex1 {
  width:150%;
}
```

Given class names I'm assuming bootstrap:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYJMrp

Comment: Thanks its working. I need to add 6 text boxes in one row. The text box is coming down https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYJMrp

Comment: as shown in image i need to show 5 text boxes with file browser. I am not getting where i making wrong in my code.